# Holomorphic Functional Calculus: Generalization

Tags: matrices, definite-integrals

So I have a matrix integral to compute of the form
$$
\int_\infty^\infty
\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}
\frac{1}{\omega-M}
P
\frac{1}{\omega+M}
$$
where $M$ is a complex invertible matrix who's spectrum lies entirely in the lower half of the complex plane and P is a rank-1 projector (and doesn't necessarily have any nice relation to M, in particular they don't commute). Naively, I would've thought that to compute this matrix, I could've just use the "residue" theorem of holomorphic functional calculus. That is, close the contour in the lower half plane, and pick up the residues to obtain
$$
\int_\infty^\infty
\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}
\frac{1}{\omega-M}
P
\frac{1}{\omega+M} =
-i P \frac{1}{2M}
$$
But of course that can't be the case, since one could also close the contour in the upper half plane to obtain
$$
\int_\infty^\infty
\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}
\frac{1}{\omega-M}
P
\frac{1}{\omega+M}
=
-i\frac{1}{2M}P
$$
But of course $M$ and $P$ don't commute, so clearly this formula can't be right. Is there a closed form expression for the this matrix in terms of $M$ and $P$ (or the inverse of M?). Thanks!